# T-SQL : merge insert old and new value then make changes

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-merge

It's my first time working with T-SQL `Merge` and I have been trying to write a Stored Procedure using with the following condition:

1. If record is present then insert into `Changes` table the Id, old value (before update) and the new value and after that update the old value from `Affected`
2. if record is not present then insert into `Changes` the Id, empty for old and the new value and after that insert new record in `Affected`
3. if record didn't match then insert into `Changes` the Id, old value (value before deletion) and empty as new value and after that delete the record

Here are the tables I used

```
CREATE TABLE Affected
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ZoneId] int NOT NULL,
    [Name] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [Value] varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE Changes
(
    [AffectedId] int NOT NULL,
    [OldValue] varchar(100),
    [NewValue] varchar(100)
)
```

And here is my stored procedure which takes two zone ids as input parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAffectChanges
    @ZoneId1 int,
    @ZoneId2 int
AS
    IF(@ZoneId1 < 10)
    BEGIN
        ;WITH fromQ AS 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Name, Value 
            FROM Affected 
            WHERE ZoneId = @ZoneId1 AND Name NOT IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')
        ), toQ AS
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Name, Value 
            FROM Affected 
            WHERE ZoneId = @ZoneId2 AND Name NOT IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')
        )
        MERGE toQ
        USING fromQ ON (toQ.Name = fromQ.Name)

        WHEN MATCHED AND fromQ.Value<>toQ.Value THEN
            ----first insert
            INSERT INTO Changes (AffectedId, OldValue, NewValue)
            VALUES(toQ.Id, toQ.Value, fromQ.Value)
            ----then update
            UPDATE SET toQ.Value=fromQ.Value

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY toQ THEN
            ----first insert
            INSERT INTO Changes (AffectedId, OldValue, NewValue)
            VALUES(toQ.Id, '', fromQ.Value)
            ----second insert 
            INSERT (Name, Zone, Value)
            VALUES (fromQ.Name, @ZoneId1, fromQ.Value)

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY fromQ THEN
            ----first insert
            INSERT INTO Changes (AffectedId, OldValue, NewValue)
            VALUES(toQ.Id, toQ.Value, '')
            ----then delete
            DELETE
    END
```

Is there a way to perform both insert to Changes and Update/Insert/Delete for `Affected`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"here is my SP which takes three zone ids as a input parameters"_... the code posted only contains 2 parameters: `@ZoneId1` and `@ZoneId2`

Comment: @gvee sorry for that. I updated the question

Comment: You should be able to use the OUTPUT clause to capture most of those audit requirements. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-the-merge-statements

Comment: Be wary of `merge` it is riddled with bugs and edge cases, always safer to use `update` then `insert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the `OUTPUT` clause to do this.**

Notes:

- `MERGE` **requires** a semi-colon terminator. `;WITH` is silly, `;` is not a beginning-ator, it is meant to be placed at the end of every command
- The options for `WHEN NOT MATCHED` are `BY SOURCE` and `BY TARGET` (this is the default)
- I don't quite understand how you have a `DISTINCT` on the target, I don't believe it is allowed, nor how it makes sense to do so.

```sql
        WITH fromQ AS 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Name, Value 
            FROM Affected 
            WHERE ZoneId = @ZoneId1 AND Name NOT IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')
        ), toQ AS
        (
            SELECT Name, Value 
            FROM Affected 
            WHERE ZoneId = @ZoneId2 AND Name NOT IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')
        )
        MERGE toQ
        USING fromQ ON (toQ.Name = fromQ.Name)

        WHEN MATCHED AND fromQ.Value <> toQ.Value THEN
            UPDATE
                SET toQ.Value = fromQ.Value

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (Name, Zone, Value)
            VALUES (fromQ.Name, @ZoneId1, fromQ.Value)

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
            DELETE

        OUTPUT inserted.Id, ISNULL(deleted.Value, ''), ISNULL(inserted.Value, '')
            INTO Changes (AffectedId, OldValue, NewValue)
        ;
```